# make[1]: cc: Command not found make[1]: *** [Makefile:366: stress-access.o] Error 127

Tags: linux, cross-compiling

I cross-compiled a stress-ng file on a VM. It worked perfectly i could run stress-ng on the VM but I needed to run it on my imx8m so I tared the file and uploaded it on the platform. I did a make (after untaring) to get the executable file but surprise ..
make[1]: cc: Command not found 
make[1]: *** [Makefile:366: stress-access.o] Error 127

I'm using Yocto so i can't sudo or get-apt ect... 
I'm begining on Linux and I don't know what to do.

Comment: `cc` is usually a link to gcc. If you have a functional gcc, please do : `cd [directory with gcc] && ln -s gcc cc` ... If you cannot do that, please try adding a line to the Makefile : `CC = gcc`

Comment: Is your imx target even set up for development? Usually that isn't the case. You should not try to build/make on the target. Just run the binaries produced by the cross-compilation. Though I have doubts whether you actually did a cross compile because you said you ran `stress-ng` in your VM. Unless the VM is an imx8 VM then it means you did a native compile and not a cross compile.